# How can I define width/height of svg-sprite and write these values to the file (with Linux or Mac CLI)

Tags: imagemagick, command-line-interface, identify, svg-sprite, imagemagick-identify

I'm trying to create svg-sprite using npm package **svg-sprite**. Eventually I get sprite, that looks like this:

```html
// icons-test.svg
...
<svg viewBox="0 0 108 54" ...>
  <svg height="54" width="54" viewBox="-2 -2 54 54" ...>
    <path d="...”>
   </svg>
  <svg height="54" width="54" viewBox="-2 -2 54 54" ...>
    <path d="...”>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

To define size (for example width) of this svg-sprite I use command **identify** from util **ImageMagick**.

```
identify -format '%w' icons-test.svg
```

or write it to the file

```
echo "\$spriteWidth = $(identify -format ‘%w’ icons-test.svg)px" >> styles.styl
```

**The problem is** that in file I don't get width of full svg-sprite (108), but only width of last sub-svg image(54), that is included in common svg-sprite.

Please, tell me where is my mistake? How to make **identify** return correct width.
Or advice me another variants to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect that the nested `svg` tags are confusing ImageMagick's internal SVG decoder. Try converting the SVG into MVG. It should throw-out the nested SVG structure.

```
$ convert icons-test.svg mvg:-
```

Which will print the following MVG instructions.

```
push graphic-context
viewbox 0 0 108 54
affine 1 0 0 1 0 0
push graphic-context
viewbox 0 0 54 54
affine 1 0 0 1 2 2
push graphic-context
path ''
pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
push graphic-context
viewbox 0 0 54 54
affine 1 0 0 1 2 2
push graphic-context
path ''
pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
pop graphic-context
```

With the nested `viewbox`s isolated to `graphic-context`s on the stack, you should be able to **identify** correctly.

```
$ convert icons-test.svg mvg:- | identify -format '%w' mvg:-
#=> 108
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Somehow:) I mean, it returns width and height for svg-sprites correctly, but on some svg-sprites it also returns some errors:
`identify: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `64' @ error/draw.c/RenderMVGContent/4361.` 
Perhaps, it's because mvg doesn't understand some svg internals? (i'm not familiar with mvg well).

Comment: And what do you think about converting svg to raster to define size?
`convert icons-test.png && identify -format '%w' icons-test.png && rm icons-test.png`

It also returns correct size (and doesn’t return errors), but is’t a good practice?
Anyway, thanks you, I’ll check it like decision.